# Как открыть порт 27015?

Tags: сеть, порты

Пытаюсь открыть порт 27015 на Win 7 Ultimate. 2ip.ru пишет, что порт закрыт, при выключенном антивирусе (Kaspersky).  IP-динамический. 2ip.ru и команда `nslookup` в командной строке выдают разные IP, соответственно IP - внутренний (правильно определил?). В брандмауэре всё открыто. Звонил провайдеру, говорят что они никаких портов кроме 21-го не закрывают. Так как же мне всё таки открыть этот порт?!

Comment: наверное кроме 25-го

Answer (score 3):

Наверное вы за NATом, поэтому порт и будет закрыт извне. Тут ничего не сделаешь, пока не появится возможность организовать "белый" ip-адрес.

Comment: @ArcherGodson, окей, это зависит от провайдера? Если позвонить им, то что нужно справшивать?

Comment: попросить выдать "белый" ип, постоянный

Comment: либо port-forwarding на порт 27015 (хотя ни одного провайдера, который бы это сделал я не знаю)

Comment: вообще если порты пров не закрывает, то надо настраивать все же проброс порта на роутере своем, например. для работы с динамическим ип можно использовать чтонить типа dyndns или no-ip... по крайней мере будет статический вебадрес... я так делал и все работало. по крайней мере vnc работает точно ;)если у вас нет роутера и инет приходит напрямую в комп, то вырубите вообще брандмауэр виндовый и проверьте, если все заработает, то копать его надо. не забудте обратно включить)

Comment: вы не правы, уже всё и так понятно, провайдер порты не закрывает, просто такой принцип работы [NAT][1]а  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT

Answer (score 2):

Закажите у провайдера услугу выделенный ip адрес(0,5-1$ в месяц обычно). Обычно в винде всего лишь надо подтвердить запрос при первом запуске сервера на выход в сеть.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте для исключения ошибок, проверить в локальной сети открытость порта, сделать прверку из сети между компьютерами. Если всё отлично, посмотрите настройки браундмаера, так же не занят ли этот порт кем то, если роутер - то просто проброс. На Linux  это делается одной строчкой.

Comment: у человека нет белого ip, какая проверка ещё нужна?